# Font option "Scale=..." displays weird behavior with Asana Math

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, asana

I am using Lualatex with the fontspec and unicode-math options, with Asana Math as my math font.

If I try to change the scale of the math font in the definition I encounter weird behavior: the scale of *most* of the signs is correctly modified but some operators become bold and very large. Here is a MWE, compiled in LuaTeX:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Scale=.6]{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n i = \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If I try to change the number in `\setmathfont[Scale=.6]{Asana Math}` here is what I obtain (at 400% zoom):
[image]

For `Scale=1.` I recover the standard font ehavior. But as soon as I set `Scale=.99` the sum symbol becomes larger and bolder, despite the rest of the symbols remaining almost unchanged! For `Scale=.6` the issue is even more apparent.

The issue seems to affect other symbols (e.g. product, integral), and occurs only in display mode. It does not appear with Latin Modern Math so I assume it may be a font issue.

Does anyone has a workaround, aside not using the scale option ? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Imho you can't use Scale with math fonts. unicode-math uses internally `Scale=1.00001,` and `Scale=0.99999` to setup some of the math and this will interfere. Better leave the math alone and scale the text font. Or make a feature request that a "MathScale" key is added.